# cpython: when PyDict_GetItem is called and when dict_subscript?

Tags: python, dictionary, cpython

I am reading cpython code for python 3k and I have noticed, that `__missing__` is called only when `dict_subscript` is called, but not when `PyDict_GetItem` is used. What is the difference between those two methods and when each is called? If I pass an PyObject that is a subclass of dict and has `__missing__` method, how can I force using it, since `PyDict_GetItem` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observations, guesses, etc:

Same happens in Python 2.x.

`dict_subscript` implements the equivalent of the high_level `dict.__getitem__` method and thus will be called whenever `adict[somekey]` appears other than on the LHS of an assignment in Python code.

`PyDict_GetItem` is part of the C API. Perhaps it's an oversight that it hasn't been updated.

Having read the dire comments at the start of `PyDict_GetItem`, I'd be using `PyDict_GetItemWithError` instead ;-)

Perhaps you can do the C-level equivalent of `my_getitem = getattr(my_dict, '__getitem__')` once then call that.

Perhaps you could raise a bug ticket or ask on comp.lang.python